# Recursive call works only for super parent and not for children

Tags: java

I am trying to get the list of strings from a REST response like below:

```
private List<String> recursiveRestCall(String folderId) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    Mono<String> mono = webClient.get().uri("/some/api/" + folderId + "/endpoint/goes/here").retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

    final ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mono.block(), ObjectNode.class);

    if (node.get("parent").get("children").isArray()) {

        for (JsonNode jsonNode : node.get("parent").get("children")) {

            if (jsonNode.get("child").get("isFile").asBoolean()) {
                fileList.add(jsonNode.toString());
            }

            if (jsonNode.get("child").get("isFolder").asBoolean()) {
                recursiveRestCall(jsonNode.get("child").get("id").toString().replaceAll("\"", "")); // This is not working and no error whatsoever.
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, as highlighted in the comment in above snippet. Only the `if (jsonNode.get("child").get("isFile").asBoolean()) {` condition is executed and I get the list items. I know there are few subfolders having files in them. So effectively the super parent's children are retrieved. But not from the child who is be a parent (as subfolder) too.

What I am missing here?

Comment: you aren't capturing teh result. e.g something like folderList.AddRange(recusiveRestCall...)

Comment: Sorry I changed it to fileList. Where I am not capturing it?

Comment: Where you call it and ignore the result. `fileList` is created per-call; if you do nothing with the returned results `fileList` is thrown away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save result of this like=

```
List<String> tempList = recursiveRestCall(jsonNode.get("child").get("id").toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
if(fileList !=null) 
    list.addAll(tempList);
```

Based on the comments, You can edit this method like below:

```
private List<String> recursiveRestCall(String folderId) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

Mono<String> mono = webClient.get().uri("/some/api/" + folderId + "/endpoint/goes/here").retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);

final ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mono.block(), ObjectNode.class);

if (node.get("parent").get("children").isArray()) {

    for (JsonNode jsonNode : node.get("parent").get("children")) {

        if (jsonNode.get("child").get("isFile").asBoolean()) {
            fileList.add(jsonNode.toString());
        }

        if (jsonNode.get("child").get("isFolder").asBoolean()) {
            fileList.addAll(recursiveRestCall(jsonNode.get("child").get("id").toString().replaceAll("\"", ""))); // This is not working and no error whatsoever.
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
return fileList;
```

}

Comment: Aye something like that.

Comment: If it returned an empty list instead of null, you wouldn't need the temporary variable. Any method that returns a list should always return an empty list if there are no results, never null.

Comment: Agree. I edited only the part that would solve the problem.